How to manually listen for updates to a SwiftData @Model object?
Let's say I have a class like this:
@Model
final class MyItem: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
    var name: String
    
    init(id: String, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

How can I listen for changes to this object in the database, not just the local instance.
class ViewModel {

 private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
 
 init(myItem: MyItem) {
       // Something like this
        item.objectWillChange.sink { completion in
            print("something")
        } receiveValue: { som in
            print("something new")
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
 }

}

I've tried conforming MyItem to ObservableObject. And using objectWillChange. This allows be to use objectWillChange.sink, but when I make changes and save, I don't see any changes. I know the changes are persisting to the DB because I see the changes stick between builds of the app.
I've tried adding @Published to var name: String, but this doesn't compile because @Model doesn't allow property wrappers.

Do you want to detect changes of the properties of the myItem instance (where "changes" means the property setter being called), or do you want to detect changes to the database record with myItem.id as the id? These are very different things, and the latter is significantly more involved.

body is called when it changes

I want to track DB changes.

yeah body changes when db changes happen. i’m wondering if it’s possible to listen for then and perform a custom operation once this record changes.

In your View, you could try using eg: .onChange(of: items.first?.name) {...}
Note, @Model macro makes the class conform to Observable, Hashable, Identifiable
no need for doing it again manually.
